# How make a content of a html table compatible with any screen resolution?

Tags: android, html, responsive-design, android-webview, responsive

I have the following html code with a `<table>` that also will be showed in mobile devices and have a trouble. If i insert much content inside this table, in devices with small resolution (small of screen), the content not will showed completally (will cut the footer  of my site).

Then how make displayed all content of my site be showed based on code below?

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="black">
<table width="100%" height="100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="center">
      <br />
      <img width="100" height="100" src="myimage.png"> <br /><br />
      <b><font color="white">My text...</font></b> <br />
      <b><font color="white">My text...<p id="randomize"></p></font></b>
      <b><font color="white">My text...<p id="lbpath"></p></font></b>
      <br />
      <img width="150" height="150" src="myimage2.gif"> <br />
      <center>
        <font color="yellow"><b>
        <p id="label">My text...</p>
        </b></font>
      </center>
      <b><font color="red">My text...</font></b><font color="white">My text...</font></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want the content of the table to be scaled down so that the whole table fits on the screen without the need for scrollbars?

Comment: @DacreDenny, i want see both possibilities. With and without scrollbars.

Comment: The code above not showed any scrollbar in a device with small screen (very strange): Ex: smartphone **Samsung J1 mini**. Already in a **Moto G5s plus**, all content is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it nessesary to set height for table?

```
<table width="100%">
```

must work fine